# Do CSRF Tokens need to be tied to user IDs?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, csrf

I am implementing a web system using Golang and have incorporated [gorilla/csrf](https://github.com/gorilla/csrf) for CSRF protection. However, I've encountered an issue. When I have `tab1` open in my browser, logged in as `user1`, and navigated to a form page, both the form and the cookie contain token-related information. Then, I open `tab2`, log out `user1`, log in as `user2`, resulting in an updated token in the form, while the data in the cookie remains unchanged. Returning to `tab1`, I perform a submission, which succeeds, but the displayed submitter is `user2`.

I am quite curious if this behavior is normal. It doesn't seem to violate the CSRF mechanism, but it's strange that the old page still functions correctly. Should I consider a way to invalidate the submission operation on the old page?

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods of CSRF protection, and most but not all need to be tied to a user (and usually a specific session). Double-submit cookies - which this library appears to use - don't require being tied to a specific user; they are in that sense stateless. *However* they do need to be changed whenever the user's identity (and ideally authorization) change, to prevent session fixation.

The scenario you describe is a variant of the classic session fixation vulnerability, wherein an attacker accesses a site, records the session token(s), and then logs out. Later, a victim comes and logs in (with their own account) on the same machine, and - because the tokens don't change - the attacker can hijack their account. In this case, the authentication token presumably does change, but the anti-CSRF token does not; as a result, the attacker can't fully hijack the victim's authenticated session, but the attacker *can* use CSRF to make the victim's browser submit attacker-chosen requests (in effect, completely bypassing CSRF protection). It's harder than without CSRF protection at all - you have to access the victim's machine prior to the victim using it - but it's viable in some scenarios.

To avoid session fixation, the token needs to change whenever the session changes (log in, log out, elevate privileges, etc.). I'm not actually sure how to force this library to do that, short of deleting the anti-CSRF cookie on session change and letting the library's middleware create a new one...

That is, of course, assuming that the cookie varies between users at all. If *everybody* gets the same cookie even across different computers, then the attacker can look up *every* user's anti-CSRF token from the comfort of their own home, and CSRF everybody. I think it doesn't work like that though; each cookie is generated uniquely (even though they're all generated from the same static "secret" key, a needless single point of failure). The problem is just ensuring that the cookie is re-generated for each user, and it sounds like currently it is not.

---

As a side note, even without reading the source code, that library has multiple questionable design choices. One of the simplest is the defaulting to no `SameSite`; there's no good reason for that default (and the readme even calls out the importance of sane defaults!). Another is the whole token-checking rigamarole when using a custom header (for script-initiated requests); that's simply unnecessary, as browsers *won't let script* add a custom header to a request unless the request is either same-origin (which is obviously not cross-site) or the server explicitly approves the cross-origin request from the relevant (attacker's) origin with specific permission to add the relevant header. Finally, double-submit cookies are a relatively weak model in general, for a few reasons but the session fixation issue is among them. It's not that it *can't* be done securely, it's that it's harder to do so and requires mitigations that this library is not using by default, or even telling you to use (like a prefixed cookie name and/or HSTS).